# DateTimePicker OnValueChanged event sending old value

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, datetimepicker

I am using the [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker) WPF control from the Extended WPF Toolkit library, version 3.3.0.

The problem I am having, is that when I fire the ValueChanged event, I am receiving the value before the change, rather than after.

My XAML look like this:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker x:Name="dtTo" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="2">
<ie:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ie:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
        <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DateToChangedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dtTo, Path=Value}"/>
    </ie:EventTrigger>
</ie:Interaction.Triggers>
```

My command looks like this:

```
public ICommand DateFromChangedCommand
{
    get
    { 
        return new DelegateCommandObject(new Action<object>((parameter) => DateFromChanged(parameter)));
    }
}
```

My DelegateCommand class looks like this:

```
public class DelegateCommandObject : ICommand
{
    public Action<object> commandTask;

    public DelegateCommandObject(Action<object> workToDo)
    {
        commandTask = workToDo;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        commandTask.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}
```

And the method being fired looks like this:

```
public void DateFromChanged(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter == null)
        return;

    DateTime? dt = parameter as DateTime?;
    This.Options.DateFrom = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}", dt);
}
```

What can I do to ensure I get the value after it is changed, rather than before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could defer checking the value.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() => 
{  
     // work with the object

}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

But I think your whole approach looks odd.
I would bind the date (Value) to a full property in a viewmodel and when the date is changed the setter gets the new value. You have a command there so you presumably have some sort of viewmodel already.

Comment: You're right about changing my approach. My thinking was to use a command because I need to format the DateTime received into a string, but I can do it elsewhere. I'm curious, is putting logic into the setter of my model to do my conversion going against MVVM structure?

Comment: Depends who you talk to. It's fairly common to copy data from a model object into a viewmodel object to avoiding polluting the model. Some people would say all that copying is a waste of time with little benefit.